# Compare enum cases with parameters

Tags: ios, swift, enums, swift3

I am developing iOS app in Swift 3 and I am face with a problem. I have an enum:

```
enum MapMode: Equatable {
    case scenes
    case temperature
    case editingScene
    case editingWaterfall(waterfall: Waterfall, mode: PumpEditorMode, waterfallScene: WaterfallScene?)
    case editingWaterfallScenes(waterfall: Waterfall)
    case editingTemperature(thermostate: Thermostat)
    case editingShutter(shutter: Device, doorDirection: DoorDirection)
    case editingDoor
    case comfortScenesList

    public static func ==(lhs: MapMode, rhs: MapMode) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case let (.editingTemperature(ther01), .editingTemperature(ther02)):
            return ther01.deviceId ?? 0 == ther02.deviceId ?? 0
        case let (a, b) where a.rawValue == b.rawValue:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

and I get an error `Value of type 'MapMode' has no member 'rawValue'` so I realize I need add raw values for enums so I edit a code to this:

```
enum MapMode: Int, Equatable {
    case scenes = 0
    case temperature = 1
    case editingScene = 2
    case editingWaterfall(waterfall: Waterfall, mode: PumpEditorMode, waterfallScene: WaterfallScene?) = 3
    case editingWaterfallScenes(waterfall: Waterfall) = 4
    case editingTemperature(thermostate: Thermostat) = 5
    case editingShutter(shutter: Device, doorDirection: DoorDirection) = 6
    case editingDoor = 7
    case comfortScenesList = 8

    public static func ==(lhs: MapMode, rhs: MapMode) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case let (.editingTemperature(ther01), .editingTemperature(ther02)):
            return ther01.deviceId ?? 0 == ther02.deviceId ?? 0
        case let (a, b) where a.rawValue == b.rawValue:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

And it is not compile too. `Enum with raw type cannot have cases with arguments`
My question is: how to make enum with parameters to be an Equatable?

#### EDIT 1: Temporary(working) solution

```
enum MapMode: Equatable {
    case scenes
    case temperature
    case editingScene
    case editingWaterfall(waterfall: Waterfall, mode: PumpEditorMode, waterfallScene: WaterfallScene?)
    case editingWaterfallScenes(waterfall: Waterfall)
    case editingTemperature(thermostate: Thermostat)
    case editingShutter(shutter: Device, doorDirection: DoorDirection)
    case editingDoor
    case comfortScenesList

    public static func ==(lhs: MapMode, rhs: MapMode) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case (.scenes, .scenes), (.temperature, .temperature), (.editingScene, .editingScene), (.editingDoor, .editingDoor), (.comfortScenesList, .comfortScenesList):
            return true
        case let (.editingTemperature(ther01), .editingTemperature(ther02)):
            return ther01.deviceId ?? 0 == ther02.deviceId ?? 0
        case let (.editingWaterfall(waterfall01, _, _), .editingWaterfall(waterfall02, _, _)):
            return waterfall01.deviceId == waterfall02.deviceId
        case let (.editingWaterfallScenes(waterfall01), .editingWaterfallScenes(waterfall02)):
            return waterfall01.deviceId == waterfall02.deviceId
        case let (.editingShutter(shutter01, _), .editingShutter(shutter02, _)):
            return shutter01.deviceId == shutter02.deviceId
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

I decided to abort `rawValues` and I expanded `==` function. This solution has a deffect. Ever time I add new `case` I need to remember to expand `==` function.

I am looking for more generic solution.

Comment: You can just specify the first value (= 0) and each successive value will increment

Comment: @Ashley Mills don't work it generates error message  `Enum with raw type cannot have cases with arguments`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to separate them into two enums:

```
enum MapMode: Equatable {
    case mapMode(mode:ModeType)
    case editingWaterfall(waterfall: Waterfall, mode: PumpEditorMode, waterfallScene: WaterfallScene?)
    case editingWaterfallScenes(waterfall: Waterfall)
    case editingTemperature(thermostate: Thermostat)
    case editingShutter(shutter: Device, doorDirection: DoorDirection)

    public static func ==(lhs: MapMode, rhs: MapMode) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case let (.editingTemperature(ther01), .editingTemperature(ther02)):
            return ther01.deviceId ?? 0 == ther02.deviceId ?? 0
        case let (mapMode(a), mapMode(b)) where a.rawValue == b.rawValue:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    } 
}

enum ModeType: Int, Equatable {
    case scenes = 0
    case temperature
    case editingScene
    case editingWaterfall
    case editingWaterfallScenes
    case editingTemperature
    case editingShutter
    case editingDoor
    case comfortScenesList

    public static func ==(lhs: ModeType, rhs: ModeType) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case let (a, b) where a.rawValue == b.rawValue:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    } 
}
```